# Tag entity-framework-3.5 deve ser removida?

Tags: debate, tags, tag-específica

[Fiz uma pergunta no site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/204717/como-inserir-um-registro-j%C3%A1-existente-no-entity-framework?noredirect=1#204717) e jurava que minha versão do `Entity Framework` era a 3.5.

Mas, pelo jeito, essa versão do EF não existe.

Essa `tag` não deveria ser removida?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim e não.

[Historicamente falando, o nome existe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574253(v=vs.113).aspx), mas só para causar confusão, porque na verdade essa versão 1 funciona em cima do framework .NET 3.5. Em 2009, [esta versão era chamada de v1](http://geekswithblogs.net/iupdateable/archive/2009/03/25/entity-framework-v1-and-v2.aspx). Como todo produto novo da Microsoft, acontece várias vezes do nome não fazer sentido.

A melhor maneira de resolver isso é criando uma tag chamada [entity-framework-v1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entity-framework-v1) e transformando a tag [entity-framework-3.5](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entity-framework-3.5) em um sinônimo.